# Как правильно поставить ударение?

Tags: орфоэпия

"ПаспортОв" или "пАспортов"?

Answer (score 2):

Во множественном числе - паспортА, паспортОв

Answer (score 1):

Именно так: во множественном числе - паспортА, паспортОв